# Javascript window.print() gives blank print preview

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to print my website using javascript but the print preview shows only header and footers and the rest is blank.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.print()">Print</a>
```

Can your guys help me on this one.

Comment: A sample of your html code would help.

Comment: Is issue only in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing like this

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript  calls window.print while the page is still loading. Instead of waiting for loading to complete and printing the correct content, it just prints a single blank page.